# Why is indexOf not working into counting were a string is

Tags: java

I am pretty sure indexOf is suppose to print out the number the letter is located! And in my code if it is there is should add to result to see how many "x" are in message! Although it dosen't work it print out 7 meaning it completely ignores my if statement!

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String message = "xyxxzax";
        int result = 0;
        int y = message.length();
        for(int x = 0 ; y > x; x++){
            String v = message.substring(x,x+1);
            if (message.indexOf("x") > -1){
                result++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This happens because you are looking for an "x" in `message`, instead of in your substring `v`

Comment: `message.indexOf("x") > -1` is always true for the message string `"xyxxzax"`. Maybe you wanted to write `v.indexOf("x") > -1`

Comment: @ThomasKläger How do you remove x if its found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you never change the string message! And I suppose you that this is not how `indexOf` works. So:

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String message = "xyxxzax";
        int result = 0;
        int y = message.length();
        for(int x = 0 ; y > x; x++){
            String v = message.substring(x,x+1);
            if (v.equals("x")){
                result++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: @CedrikPICARD ```indexOf```returns the first elements that you are looking for in a string, but you never changed the string, and it's never going to delete the string it finds for you.

Comment: So in your if statement, ```message.indexOf("x") > -1``` always return true.